# Overwrote Windows User folder with Contacts folder, how to get it back?

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

I have been changing the location of the default Windows 8 user files; my music, my pictures etc…

Unfortunately when i was changing the location of the Contacts folder I selected the wrong location and selected: `C:\Users\Windows User`

Now the `Windows User` folder has been replaced by the `Contacts` folder.

I have tried changing it back but get an error:

> Can’t move the folder because there is a folder in the same location
>   that can't be redirected. Access is denied.

How can I change the location of the contacts folder and get my `Windows User` folder back?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions for your situation specifically:

- Try making a new (third) folder somewhere else, and re-point your contacts location to it.  If that breaks the contacts/user folder overload, now try moving from the third folder back to wherever you want your (final) contacts to be.
- Could you also manually move the address book to your new folder?

For anyone else wondering how to change the location of their Windows 8 shortcuts:

- While in desktop mode, hit Windows key-X
- Choose "file explorer"
- Right-click on any of the folders under your user name ("documents", "contacts", etc.), and choose "properties"
- Select the "Location" tab and change the path there